# How to find bounding-layer for a threshold number in numpy stacked arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Lets assume I have 3 (or 100) ndarrays with dim=2 and shape=(x, y), that are stacked on top of each other.

For each index in an array below another array, the values are smaller for the one below compared to the values of the one above, like so:

```
A = 
[ 0 0 1 1
  0 0 0 1 
  0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 ]
B = 
[ 2 2 2 2
  2 2 2 2
  1 2 2 2
  1 1 2 2 ]
C =
[ 3 4 4 3
  3 4 4 4
  2 3 4 4
  2 2 2 4 ]
```

Given a number (for example 1.5), I want to find

```
  for each (x, y) of the ndarrays:
    (1) the index of the stacked array, that has the biggest value below and
    (2) the index of the stacked array, that has the smalest value above the number
that is, the sourunding "bouding layer" of the number)
```

For the example arrays above, that would be:
Indices of layer below threshold

```
I_biggest_smaller_number = 
[ 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0
  1 1 0 0 ]
```

Indices of layer above threshold

```
I_smallest_bigger_number = 
[ 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1
  2 1 1 1
  2 2 1 1]
```

In the most efficient manner with numpy. Any help woul be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to use a combination of NumPy's `max`, `min`, and `where` functions.

Using `numpy.where` allows us to find the index of matrix entries based of a criteria. In this case we can ask what the index is of the value which is the maximum/minimum of a subset of matrix entries (more or less than a given number).

This is quite a mouthful but hopefully the code included here should help. Be careful though: in your example, the values in `B[3,2]` and `C[3,2]` are the same. Maybe this was a typo; however, I made some assumptions about this in the code below.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,0,1,1],
              [0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0]])

B = np.array([[2,2,2,2],
              [2,2,2,2],
              [1,2,2,2],
              [1,1,2,2]])

C = np.array([[3,4,4,3],
              [3,4,4,4],
              [2,3,4,4],
              [2,2,2,4]])

# I assume the arrays are stacked like this                           
stacked_arrays = np.array([A,B,C])
# So the shape of stacked_arrays in this case is (3,4,4)

n = 1.5 # The example value you gave

I_biggest_smaller_number=np.ndarray((4,4),np.int)
I_smallest_bigger_number=np.ndarray((4,4),np.int)

for x in xrange(stacked_arrays.shape[1]):
    for y in xrange(stacked_arrays.shape[2]):

        # Take values we are interested in; i.e. all values for (x,y)
        temp = stacked_arrays[:,x,y]

        # Find index of maximum value below n
        I_biggest_smaller_number[x,y]=np.where(temp==np.max(temp[np.where(temp<n)]))[0][-1]
# The [-1] takes the highest index if there are duplicates

        # Find index of minimum value above n
        I_smallest_bigger_number[x,y]=np.where(temp==np.min(temp[np.where(temp>n)]))[0][0]
# The [0] takes the lowest index if there are duplicates

print I_biggest_smaller_number
print
print I_smallest_bigger_number
```

Comment: Cool!, thanks :) Is there a way to do it without for-loops directly using numpy's functions?

Comment: I spent some time thinking about it and I don't know of a way without for-loops.